# Can't get 4k @ 60hz, only 30hz

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, 4k-monitor

I have a lenovo thinkpad t490 with "i7-8665U" which supports 4k@60hz over usb-c/thunderbolt ports according to:

- intel docs: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/pl/pl/ark/products/193563/intel-core-i7-8665u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz.html
- lenovo manual: https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t490_t590_p43s_p53s_ug_v2_en.pdf?linkTrack=PSP:ProductInfo:UserGuide

It is connected via usb-c to hdmi2.0 cable to acer vg280k.

All of that with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

xrandr doesn't show 4k@60hz mode:

```
...
DP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (0xa4) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  1074432
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     HDMI-1
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0004724707a7f65001
        0f1e0103803e22782aad65ad50459f25
        0e5054bfef80714f8140818081c08100
        9500b300d1c04dd000a0f0703e803030
        35006d552100001a565e00a0a0a02950
        302035006d552100001e000000fd0028
        3c1ea03c000a202020202020000000fc
        0056473238304b0a202020202020011e
        02034df151010304121305141f100706
        025d5e5f606123090707830100006d03
        0c001000383c20006001020367d85dc4
        01788003681a00000101283ce6e305e3
        01e40f008001e6060701606045023a80
        1871382d40582c45006d552100001e8c
        0ad08a20e02d10103e96006d55210000
        180000000000000000000000000000a6
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 92 
        supported: 92
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  3840x2160 (0xa4) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync *current
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  30.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0xa5) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4896 end 4984 total 5280 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  25.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0xa6) 297.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  54.00KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  24.00Hz
  3840x2160 (0xa7) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 4016 end 4104 total 4400 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  29.97Hz
  3840x2160 (0xa8) 296.703MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  3840 start 5116 end 5204 total 5500 skew    0 clock  53.95KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2168 end 2178 total 2250           clock  23.98Hz
  2560x1440 (0xa9) 241.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2608 end 2640 total 2720 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1481           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080 (0xaa) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0xab) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0xac) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080i (0xad) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.75KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0xae) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  28.12KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080i (0xaf) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync Interlace
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  33.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1094 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4e) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x1024 (0xb0) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x55) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0xb1) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
  1280x960 (0x59) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x800 (0x63) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0xb2) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0xb3) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0xb4) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0xb5) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0xb6) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0xb7) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x6a) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  832x624 (0xb8) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0xb9) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0xba) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x79) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x7a) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  720x576 (0xbb) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0xbc) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0xbd) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0xbe) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0xbf) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0xc0) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0xc1) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x88) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0xc2) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  1074432
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     DP-1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 99 
        supported: 99
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  1074432
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     HDMI-2
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 105 
        supported: 105
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x46
    Timestamp:  1074432
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     DP-2
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 110 
        supported: 110
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
```

When I add manualy mode generated via `cvt` (restricted or not) I get this error:

```
$ xrandr --output DP-1 --mode "3840x2160R"  --verbose
crtc 0:   3840x2160R  59.97 +0+0 "DP-1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
```

Comment: You indicated that this resolution and refresh rate are supported with USB-C and Thunderbolt, but you say you are using an HDMI adapter and your command output suggest you're using DisplayPort.  Which is it?  Keep in mind if you're using an adapter, you're restricted by the lowest common denominator.

Comment: I'm using usb-c to hdmi2.0 cable/adapter. DP-1 in xrandr output is just one of usb-c outputs on my laptop.

Comment: @Nmath That is not how it works. usb-c/thunderbolt are laptop outputs that support 60fps, not required monitor inputs. That monitor supports 4k@60 via hdmi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up buying cable explicitly supporting 4k@60hz

Comment: That's almost like say the solution was to turn it on or plug it in. The difference is it had to be plugged in **properly**.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on my laptop, HP ProBook 450 G7. I was only getting 4K@30Hz. After research, I purchased a USB-C to HDMI cable, which solved the problem. Strangely, HDMI port was limited to 30Hz, but USB-C port went up to 60Hz. Hope this helps someone

Comment: I have the HP Envy 15.6-inch i7-10750H (15-EP0048TX) and I'm having the same problem.
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS, and the USB-C to DP adaptor is pumping out 4K@60hz, but the HDMI port on 4K@30Hz.

The i7-10750H has HDMI 2.0a support, which means it should output at 60Hz. So I'm not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone googles the issue and finds this:
I had the same issue and for me the fix was to use HDMI directly. I had an adapter for DP to HDMI, same setup was working on Windows with 4k 60Hz through that adapter, but after I installed Ubuntu it only picked up 30Hz. After I removed the adapted and plugged the HDMI cable directly into the GPU, I did a reboot, and it picked up this profile by default:

HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1872mm x 1053mm
3840x2160     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98

I was using the adapted because I have two monitors with HDMI, and the GPU has only one HDMI output and 3 DP ports. The other monitor is only 1080p, so it's working ok through that adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 15 with an Anker USB-C to HDMI adapter and Full HD insted of 4k but the reason was switching the USB-C port instead of the cable.

Presumably not all USB-C ports support 60 Hz or there is a problem on my machine. Also apart from 60Hz being unavailable in the display settings, I noted that the resolution was 1920x1080i (instead of 1920x1080).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and solved by replacing a HDMI cable by a DisplayPort cable.
My USB-C dock and screen have both ports available. Using HDMI, I could only select 4k@30Hz. Selecting 60Hz would go dark and switch back. After using a DisplayPort cable, everything worked flawlessly.